# Apache leads to /var/www on virtual host

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, virtualhost, redirect

I've set up tens of sites before, I've been following the same process as always, but for some reason whenever i visit www.mysite.com, the apache server loads /var/www (the default virtual host) instead of the mysite.com virtual host.

going to mysite.com (without the www) works and goes to the right place (/home/mysite/public_html).

This is mysite.com on /etc/apache2/sites-available/:

```
# Place any notes or comments you have here
# It will make any customisation easier to understand in the weeks to come

# domain: domain1.com
# public: /home/demo/public_html/domain1.com/

<VirtualHost *:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin info@mysite.com
  ServerName  mysite.com
  ServerAlias www.mysite.com


  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/mysite/public_html


  # Custom log file locations


  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/mysite/public_html/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /home/mysite/public_html/logs/access.log combined

  </VirtualHost>
```

These are the DNS records (last block removed):

```
    A       204.62.14.xxx
MX  10  mail.mysite.com.
NS      ns1.6sync.net.
NS      ns2.6sync.net.
NS      ns3.6sync.net.
mail    A       204.62.14.xxx
www A       204.62.14.xxx
```

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04, i've reloaded and restarted the apache server multiple times.

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your apache.conf before the include directives try setting a ServerName - even though it's the default.

Comment: What should I set it to? mysite.com is not the only virtual host i'm planning to have on this machine..

Comment: SOme kind of name for the server. web.mysite.com e.g.